# Confused by syntax for mapping values from Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using `Object.keys()` to display values from key/value pairs. It works, but I'm having trouble understanding *why* it works.

```
const data = {
  question: "Why does this work?",
  language: "JavaScript",
  upvotes: 0
};

// #1: ["question", "language", "upvotes"]
console.log(Object.keys(data).map(key => key));

// #2: [{…data…}, {…data…}, {…data…}, {…data…}]
console.log(Object.keys(data).map(key => data));

// #3: ["Why does this work?", "JavaScript", 0]
console.log(Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]));
```

In example #3, why is `data[key]` the magic phrase to access a value? I would expect it to be something like `key => key[value]`

Comment: Because `data` is your object and `key` is the key?

Comment: `key` is a string, `data` is your object.

Comment: object[key] = value?

Comment: @kburgie _“object[key] = value?”_ — What are you asking?

Comment: Btw, you could just use `Object.values(data)` :-)

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each key of an object is a string. When you iterate over the `Object.keys` of an object, you're iterating over strings, so with

```
Object.keys(data).map(key
```

`key` is a string.

When `data` is the object, `data[key]` will access the value of that key, which is just ordinary bracket notation:

```js
const data = {
  question: "Why does this work?",
  language: "JavaScript",
  upvotes: 0
};

const key = 'language';
const langVal = data[key];
console.log(langVal);
```

When you do

```
.map(key => data[key])
```

it's the same thing, just inside a loop.

Note that if you want object values, it's easier just to use `Object.values`:

```js
const data = {
  question: "Why does this work?",
  language: "JavaScript",
  upvotes: 0
};

const values = Object.values(data);
console.log(values);
```